# How to replace first instance of x after y amount of characters in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to use a formula to replace the first instance of a character, starting the search after a specific amount of characters from the right (including spaces). *e.g.* in the sentence:

```
  One two three four Five six seven eight nine.
```

I would like to replace the first instance of a space (" ") with an underscore, starting the search after 17 characters (after "u" in the word "four") so the formula returns:

```
  One two three four_Five Six seven eight nine.
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `REPLACE`:

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND(" ",A1,17),1,"_")
```

Comment: That's an even smoother answer!

Answer (score 0):

What about below formula. Try it...

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,17)-1) & "_" & MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,17),LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1,17)+1)
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! I added an extra "+1" to avoid the extra space after the underscore: `=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,17)-1) & "_" & MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,17)+1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1,17)+1)`

Comment: @Myslnik If you found it working, you should accept (tick as green) answer.